# How to set and entire Fragment view on setOnLongClickListener?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to set up an entire fragment on setOnLongClickListener.  I can get the context menu to appear when i set up setOnLongCLickListener for other view object like TextView but not for when the user long clicks anywhere on the screen (fragment).  Please can someone help?  This is the code that I have:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_article_fragment, parent, false);

          v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }

            mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            view.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the OnLongClickListener on the parent layout of your fragment. If it's a linearlayout:

```
  LinearLayout fragment_linearlayout= (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_linear_layout);
    fragment_linearlayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
              mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
              return true;

        }

    });
```

Comment: thanks man it worked. great suggestion.  i cant give you any more points as i need atleast 15 reps to vote this answer up.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Happy coding :)